# must a measure-preserving and order-preserving bijection have measurable inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, order-theory, measurable-functions

Let $E$ and $F$ be measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.  We say that $m:E\to F$ is **measure-preserving** if for each measurable subset $A$ of $F$, the set $m^{-1}(A)$ is also measurable, and $\lambda[m^{-1}(A)]=\lambda(A)$.  We say that it is **order-preserving** if $x\leq y\in E$ implies $m(x)\leq m(y)$ in $F$.

**Conjecture 1.** If $m:E\to F$ is a bijection which is both measure-preserving and order-preserving, then $m^{-1}$ is measurable w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, i.e. for each Lebesgue-measurable subset $A$ of $E$, the image $m(A)$ is also Lebesgue-measurable.

**Fact 1.**  If $m:E\to F$ is a bijection which is both measure-preserving and order-preserving, then $m$ and $m^{-1}$ are both *strictly* order-preserving, i.e. $x<y\in E$ if and only if $m(x)<m(y)$ in $F$.

**Fact 2.**  If $A$ is a measurable subset of $E$ and $m(A)$ is a measurable subset of $F$ then $\lambda(A)=\lambda[m(A)]$.

My idea was to attempt an argument from contradiction.  Assume $A$ is a measurable subset of $E$ with $m(A)$ nonmeasurable.  By removing at most countably many sets of positive measure if necessary, we can assume that $m(A)$ contains no sets of positive measure.  We may also assume that $m(A)$ is contained in some finite interval $[a,b]$.  Now $B:=([a,b]\cap F)\setminus m(A)$ also is nonmeasurable, with $m^{-1}(B)$ disjoint from $A$.  Let us remove any sets of positive measure from $B$ as well.  Now $C:=m(A)\cup B$ is still measurable, because it is equal to $F\cap[a,b]$ with countably many measurable sets removed.  Note that $C$ cannot have measure zero since it has nonmeasurable subsets.  It follows that $A\cup m^{-1}(B)$ has positive measure.

Now let's see if we can bring order into it.  Consider the case where there exists a nonmeasurable subset $D$ of $m(A)$ such that $m^{-1}(B)$ does not intersect the interval $(\inf D,\sup D)$.  Then $(\inf D,\sup D)\cap C=(\inf D,\sup D)\cap m(A)=D\setminus\{\inf D,\sup D\}$, which is impossible since $(\inf D,\sup D)\cap C$ is measurable whereas $D\setminus\{\inf D,\sup D\}$ is not.  A similar argument holds for $B$.  It follows that we can assume without loss of generality that there exists a subset $G$ of $m(A)$ and a subset $H$ of $B$ such that for each $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ there are measure-zero subsets  $A_g$ of $m(A)$ and $B_h$ of $B$ such that $A_g<B_h$ if and only if $g<h$, and $B_h<A_g$ otherwise.  As only countably many of the $A_g$'s and $B_h$'s have positive diameter, we may assume without loss of generality that they are all singletons.  Now if $x<y\in m(A)$ then there is $z\in B$ with $x<z<y$.  An analogous fact holds for $A$ and $m^{-1}(B)$.

So, to summarize, we have a measurable subset $A$ of $E$, of finite diameter, and a nonmeasurable subset $B$ of $F$ which does not intersect $m(A)$, also of finite diameter, such that $m^{-1}(B)$ is measurable and of finite diameter and does not intersect $A$, $m(A)$ is nonmeasurable and of finite diameter, that $A\cup m^{-1}(B)$ and $m(A)\cup B$ both have positive measure, neither $m(A)$ nor $B$ contain any subsets of positive measure, and for every $x<y\in m(A)$ there is $z\in B$ with $x<z<y$, and an analogous fact holds for $A$ and $m^{-1}(B)$, i.e. for any $x<y\in A$ there is $z\in m^{-1}(B)$ with $x<z<y$.

Is there any way to use those order properties to achieve a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that every order-preserving map $f:E \to F$ is measurable, because the preimage of any interval is an intersection of an interval with $E$, so it is measurable. Since the inverse of an order-preserving bijection $m$ is order-preserving, it is measurable. The assumption of preserving Lebesgue measure is not needed.

**Added:** The above solution assumes the standard definition of measurability for real-valued functions: $f$ is Lebesgue-measurable if every sub-level set $\{ x \in E: f(x)<\alpha \}$ is Lebesgue-measurable, or equivalently if every preimage of a Borel set is Lebesgue measurable. Using the alternative definition that $f$ is measurable if every preimage of a Lebesgue-measurable set is Lebesgue-measurable, one indeed needs at least a weak form of the measure-preserving property. Since the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to Lebesgue measure, a set $A$ is Lebesgue measurable iff there exists a Borel set $B$ with $\lambda (A \Delta B) = 0$, where $A \Delta B  = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$. Then, using $f=m^{-1}$, we have $f^{-1}(B) = m(B)$ is a Borel set by the argument above, and $f^{-1}(A) \Delta f^{-1}(B) = m(A)\Delta m(B) = m(A \Delta B)$ is a Lebesgue null set because $m$ preserves Lebesgue measure. (We really only need that $m$-images of null sets are null sets here, which follows from the fact that every Lebesgue null set is contained in a Borel null set, whose image is then again a Borel null set.) This shows that $f^{-1}(B)$ is Lebesgue measurable, so that $f=m^{-1}$ is measurable with respect to this definition, too.

Comment: Sorry but when I say "measurable" I mean w.r.t the Lebesgue measure not the Borel measure.

Comment: Ben W: Typically even Lebesgue-measurability for functions is defined as the property that sub-level sets $\{ x\in E : f(x) < \alpha \}$ are Lebesgue measurable, or equivalently that preimages of Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable. Do you mean the definition that preimages of Lebesgue measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Ben W: I added an additional argument for this alternative definition of measurability.

Comment: I appreciate the addendum but $m$ is already measurable by definition of measure-preserving transformations. I need to show that $m^{-1}$ is measurable, or exhibit a counterexample.

Comment: Ben W: Oops, sorry, but the argument is identical, except that we only need that images of null sets are null sets, not preimages. Argument is fixed now.

Comment: When we say that $m$ preserves Lebesgue measure, we mean that if $A$ is a measurable subset of $F$ then then $m^{-1}(A)$ is a measurable subset of $E$ with the same measure. This does not obviously imply that if $A$ is a zero-measure subset of $E$ then $m(A)$ is a measurable subset of $F$.

Comment: Ben W: In the second sentence of your question you say that measure-preserving means that the Lebesgue measure of the preimage is the same as the Lebesgue measure of the set. I am honestly a little confused now...

Comment: That's right.  If $m(A)$ is measurable then $A$ has the same measure.  But there is no guaranteeing that $m(A)$ is measurable.  Not that I can see, anyway.

Comment: Also, without the assumption that $m$-images of null sets are null sets the claim is not true. E.g., take $m$ to be a strictly increasing map from the standard Cantor set $E$ to a "fat" Cantor set $F$, i.e., a Cantor set of positive measure. Then $m^{-1}(A)$ is always of measure zero, so it is Lebesgue measurable for every Lebesgue measurable set $A$. However, there are non-Lebesgue measurable sets $B \subset F$, so $m^{-1}$ is not Lebesgue-to-Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: By definition of measure-preserving transformations, $E$ and $F$ have the same measure. Sorry, I know you're trying to help, and I appreciate that.  But do you see why I thought this was a pretty difficult problem?

Comment: No, it is not that difficult, but I see where your problem is. If $N\subseteq E$ is a null set, then it is contained in a Borel null set $M \subseteq E$, which $m$ maps to a Borel null set in $F$, so $m(E) \subseteq m(M)$ is also a null set. (I did not add this argument above, but I could spell it out if you want.)

Comment: No, I don't think this will work as is. We are claiming that every null set is contained in a borel null set. This is true for $\mathbb{R}$ but not for an arbitrary Lebesgue-measurable set $E$. Bit the idea is promising. I believe it can be made to work with the borel algebra on the subspace topologies.

Comment: Maybe the most straightforward way to argue is through coverings with intervals: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist open intervals $(I_k)$ with $N \subseteq \bigcup_k I_k$ and $\sum_k \lambda(I_k) < \epsilon$. Then $m(I_k \cap E) = J_k \cap F$ with intervals $J_k$ (not necessarily open), and by measure-preservation $\lambda(J_k \cap F) = \lambda(I_k \cap E)$. Then $m(N) \subseteq \bigcup_k (J_k \cap F)$ has outer measure $< \epsilon$, which implies that $N$ is a null set. You are right that I glossed over some of these technical difficulties...

Comment: The argument works with two gaps: Let $\tau_E$ and $\tau_F$ be the subspace topologies on $E$ and $F$ so that $\sigma(\tau_E)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebras w.r.t. $\tau_E$, and similarly for $\tau_F$. **(1)** We need to show that $\sigma(\tau_E)=\{E\cap B:B\in\mathcal{B}\}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. The same will then be true for $\sigma(\tau_F)$. This way it follows that for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\{x\in E:m(x)<c\}\in\sigma(\tau_F)$. **(2)** Now we need to show that this implies $m(B)\in\sigma(\tau_F)$ for every $B\in\sigma(\tau_E)$.